# Token Not Searchable in Solana Explorer

Tags: spl-token, metadata, explorers

I have created a new token called UBXP:
https://solscan.io/token/HTskJUiHaGzWMEqreucDGJuft3Zco4en2dRkzJ3WRHkh#metadata
https://explorer.solana.com/address/HTskJUiHaGzWMEqreucDGJuft3Zco4en2dRkzJ3WRHkh

When I search "ubxp" on Solscan, my token shows up. Huzzah!

However, when I search "ubxp" on the Solana Explorer, it does not.

How do I get UBXP to show up in the search results of Solana Explorer?

Thank you very much. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I found this message when trying to view your token:
"""
Warning! Token names and logos are not unique. This token may have spoofed its name and logo to look like another token. Verify the token's mint address to ensure it is correct.
"""
It seems that Solana Explorer is not programmed to search for tokens with similar names. And this is quite common on Solana Devnet or Testnet and with most alt coins on Solana explorer.
Don't worry I think you can still search them based on token address.
Hope it will be useful to you.